# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+u) -\ln 2}{(u+1)\sqrt{u} \ln u} du$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Please help me with evaluate the following improper integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+u) -\ln 2}{(u+1)\sqrt{u} \ln u} du.$$

Comment: It doesn't converge.

Comment: Are you sure you got the limits of integration right?

Comment: At $\infty$, the integrand behaves like $u\mapsto 1/\sqrt{u}$.  This is a heavy tail and the integral will diverge at $\infty$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the considered integral be $I$. Use the substitution $u=\tan^2\theta \Rightarrow du=2\tan\theta \sec^2\theta\,d\theta$ to obtain:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(1+\tan^2\theta)-\ln 2}{(1+\tan^2\theta)\tan \theta \ln(\tan^2\theta)}2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$$

Since $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$,
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\ln(\sec\theta)-\ln 2}{\sec^2\theta \tan\theta (2\ln(\tan\theta))}2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{-2\ln(\cos\theta)-\ln 2}{\ln(\tan\theta)}d\,\theta\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$
Using the property of definite integrals which states that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx$, we can write:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{-2\ln(\sin\theta)-\ln 2}{\ln(\cot\theta)}\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2\ln(\sin\theta)+\ln 2}{\ln(\tan\theta)}\,d\theta\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(**)$$

Add $(*)$ and $(**)$ to obtain:
$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\ln(\sin\theta)-2\ln(\cos\theta)}{\ln(\tan\theta)}\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\ln(\tan\theta)}{\ln(\tan\theta)}\,d\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\,d\theta=\boxed{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: Nice answer, Pranav. +1

Comment: Thank you Random Variable! :)

Comment: +1 bro! I often see you here recently, are you bored on brilliant? :D

Comment: No, I am not bored of Brilliant, I am just trying to look for more Calculus problems, that's all and I have seen everybody talk about SE websites so I finally decided to join. :)